# Unable to retrieve the value of Dynamic Select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a button that will retrieve the value of two select boxes. I can get the value of `$("#parent_selection_pbrand").val(value.CellphoneBrand);` but `$("#child_selection_pmodel").val(value.CellphoneModel);` doesn't show the value on the select box. Any help on this is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
function retrieveListItems() {
var title = $("#txtTitle").val();
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ComputerEquipment')  /items?"+
    "$select=Id,Title,Department,Location,CellphoneBrand,CellphoneModell,CellphoneIMEI&$filter=(Title eq '"+title+"')";

$.ajax({
    url: fullUrl,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: onQuerySucceeded,

});

        function onQuerySucceeded(data) {
            var listItemInfo = '';
         $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
        $("#parent_selection_pbrand").val(value.CellphoneBrand);
        $("#child_selection_pmodel").val(value.CellphoneModel);}
```

HTML code

```
<strong>Brand:</strong>
        <div class="wrapper">
                <select name="parent_selection_pbrand" id="parent_selection_pbrand">
                    <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
                    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                    <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
                </select>
<select name="child_selection_pmodel" id="child_selection_pmodel">
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
var Apple = [
                {display: "iPhone5", value: "iPhone5" }, 
                {display: "iPhone6", value: "iPhone6" }]; 

var Samsung = [
                {display: "Samsung S5", value: "Samsung S5" }, 
                {display: "Samsung S6", value: "Samsung S6" }]; 

            //If parent option is changed
            $("#parent_selection_pbrand").change(function() {
                    var parent = $(this).val(); //get option value from parent 

                    switch(parent){ //using switch compare selected option and populate child
                          case 'Apple':
                            listphone(Apple);
                            break;
                          case 'Samsung':
                            listphone(Samsung);
                            break;              
                        default: //default child option is blank
                            $("#child_selection_pmodel").html('');  
                            break;
                       }
            });

            //function to populate child select box
            function listphone(array_list)
            {
                $("#child_selection_pmodel").html(""); //reset child options
                $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options 
                    $("#child_selection_pmodel").append("<option value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");

                });
                }
```

Comment: Are you trying to **get** the value or **set** the value? Your question says get but the code is a setter method `$("#parent_selection_pbrand").val(value.CellphoneBrand)`

Comment: I want to display the value on the select box.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean. Are you wanting to show some value as an `option` in the select box? Like `$("#parent_selection_pbrand").append('<option>'+value.CellphoneBrand+'</option>')`?

Comment: Yes. I want to show the selected option value.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `.val()` on a `<select>` element will only work if there is a corresponding `<option>` element inside the `<select>` with such value. Such as:

```
<select id="child_selection_pmodel">
    ...
    <option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
```

If I did `$("#child_selection_pmodel").val("test")` in this case it would change to the option `Test`. Otherwise nothing would visibility happen. In your case it seems that there isn't a option with the value `value.CellphoneModel` in `child_selection_pmodel` after being populated.

If you would like to add that to the `<select>` you can use `.append()`:

```
$("#child_selection_pmodel").append("<option value='...'>...</option>");
```

Comment: It doesn't work even if I put value on a <select> element. I also tried $("#child_selection_pmodel").val("test") but still empty.